# When calling XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize() on Xerces?

Tags: c++, xerces-c

I'm using Xerces and references are not very clear about when using Initialize and Terminate.

Well, many web sites typically tells you: "Always put your Xerces code between these two lines".

But do I always have to do that? Or just when parsing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call this `Initialize` once per process, before you use any Xerces-C++ functionality. You have to call `Terminate` once per process, when you're finished using Xerces.

The obvious place to put these is either `main`, in a singleton object, or in some RAII object that is in scope while Xerces is used.

Comment: In C++ I would use RAII to do this. A singleton object is not needed because it would have no external state.